# Best way to create test data for all django apps unittest

Tags: django, python-unittest

I want to setup django test data for all app unit tests, like create a user before all tests running, and then the test in each app test could use that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not generating a base class for all your tests that do need this user. Create it in the setUp Method of that Class or use an fixture in this base class

eg. like this :

```
class ViewMethodsTestCase(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['initial_data.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = ShrUser.objects.create_user(username="lala", 
             password="lala", email="lala0@localhost")
        loggedIn = self.client.login(username="lala", password="lala")
        self.assertTrue(loggedIn, "not logged in")
```